# Разделение на frontend и backend есть только в вебе?

Tags: gui

У меня несколько вопросов по поводу разделений задач.
В мобильной или десктопной разработке всё также делится на фронт и бэк, как и профессии?
И вообще как программ на java, c++, python, и прочим подобным делают gui (я в курсе про QT tkinter для питона, меня интересует есть ли другие профессиональные корпоративные решения)

Comment: Чисто технически в мобильной и десктоп разработке аналогом будет деление клиент/сервер. Но отдельных профессий "верстальщика gui приложений" или только-gui программистов нет.